# Connection string for anonymous user

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have a website that is used for uploading data to a restricted database.  Usually when I built out connection strings for SQL Server inserts, it was from an in house user so I could use windows authentication, what's the best practice for when the user does not have access to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to authorize your IIS APPpool where your website is running on... You can simply do this by creating a user in sqlserver.... FOr example IISApppool\Yourapppoolname. You can find the name of the pool where your site is running in the IIS manager.

Answer (score 1):

Yes exactly, read this article msdn it's very interessant

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.71).aspx

Link  :  http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I'am happy to help you BlueM Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a SQL user specific to the website.